# In couchbase, how can I select a value from array key?

Tags: sql, couchbase

I'm starting with Couchbase, because the feature of NoSQL and the implementation for the N1QL, similar as SQL syntax.

So, I'm trying to SELECT a value from array key, but there is no success... how can I filter these results?

[image]

```
SELECT players p FROM matches WHERE p. ???? = 'Aloh4'
```

Comment: Is that possible without a view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT players FROM matches WHERE 'Aloh4' IN OBJECT_NAMES(players);

OR

CREATE INDEX ix1 ON matches( DISTINCT ARRAY pname FOR pname IN OBJECT_NAMES(players) END);
SELECT players FROM matches WHERE ANY pname IN OBJECT_NAMES(players) SATISFIES pname = 'Aloh4' END;